# Slice multiple part from single image in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, crop, slice

I am working in iPhone application, I have tried to slice multiple part from single image but i can't get exact solution. I want single image to slice multiple part like 3x3, 4x4, 5x5, 6x6 etc... How to do this? Is it possible to do this? please help me.

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
UIImage* whole = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
    int partId = 0;
    for (int x=0; x<=300; x+=100)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<=300; y+=100)
        {

            CGImageRef cgImg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(whole.CGImage, CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100));
            UIImage* part = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
            UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:part];

            switch (partId)
            {
                case 0:
                    img.image=iv.image;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    img2.image=iv.image;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    img3.image=iv.image;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    img4.image=iv.image;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    img5.image=iv.image;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    img6.image=iv.image;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    img7.image=iv.image;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    img8.image=iv.image;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    img9.image=iv.image;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            partId++;
            NSLog(@"part id = %d",partId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you currently have and tell us what it does wrong.

Comment: thnaks for your reply

Comment: please see above, now i update this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (NSArray*)splitImageIntoRects:(CGImageRef)anImage
{
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(anImage), CGImageGetHeight(anImage));

    NSMutableArray *splitLayers = [NSMutableArray array];

    kXSlices = 3;
    kYSlices = 3;        

    for(int x = 0;x < kXSlices;x++) {
        for(int y = 0;y < kYSlices;y++) {
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake((imageSize.width / kXSlices) * x,
                                 (imageSize.height / kYSlices) * y,
                                 (imageSize.width / kXSlices),
                                 (imageSize.height / kYSlices));

            CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
            layer.frame = frame;                                                    
            CGImageRef subimage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(drawnImage, frame);
            layer.contents = (id)subimage;
            CFRelease(subimage);
            [splitLayers addObject:layer];
        }
    }
    return splitLayers; 
}
```

Note: To get an CGImageRef:

```
CGImageRef anImage = [myUIImage CGImage];
```

convert CGImageRef into UIImage

```
CALayer *layer = [splitLayers objectAtIndex:0];
CGImageRef imgRef = layer.contents;
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
ImageView1.image = img;
```

Comment: how to add splited image to uiimage

Comment: ImageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[splitLayers objectAtIndex:0]]; // Error comes libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: You can't add a CALayer to an image view. Instead use '[[splitLayers objectAtIndex:0] content]'.